# Copy Parts of a list to another list

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I am currently trying to copy sections of one list to another list and I am having a hard time.

I am very new to using lists.

I have created a constructor.

Then I have created a list that contains all of the items that I need.
I want to copy a random piece from my first list into my second list.
I then want to remove the piece that I copied from my the original list.

This is the current code I have.

My Constructor Code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Character_Setup {

    // Declare Attributes
    public int Agility = 1;
    public int Stamina = 1;
    public int Strength = 1;
    public int Critical_Hit = 1;
    public string Weapon ="";


    // Declare Stats
    public int Speed = 1;
    public int Health= 2;
    public int Damage = 3;
    public int Acuity = 4;

    public Character_Setup(string _name)
    {
        Weapon = _name;
        Speed = Agility * Random.Range (1,10);
        Health = Stamina * Random.Range (1,10);
        Damage = Strength * Random.Range (1,10);
        Critical_Hit = Acuity * Random.Range (1,10);

    }

}
```

This is my current attempt at the code to copy from one group to another.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Game_Play : MonoBehaviour {

    public int Num_Players = 11;
    public int Players = 1;




    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        //Create a list
        // Using Character_Setup
        //add 10 characters to list

        List <Character_Setup> Characters = new List<Character_Setup> ();

        Characters.Add (new Character_Setup ("Flamethrower"));
        Characters.Add (new Character_Setup ("Shotgun"));
        Characters.Add (new Character_Setup ("Rifle"));
        Characters.Add (new Character_Setup ("Pistol"));
        Characters.Add (new Character_Setup ("Machine Gun"));
        Characters.Add (new Character_Setup ("Grenade Launcher"));
        Characters.Add (new Character_Setup ("Knife"));
        Characters.Add (new Character_Setup ("Rocket Launcher"));
        Characters.Add (new Character_Setup ("Throwing Star"));
        Characters.Add (new Character_Setup ("Sling Shot"));



        /*foreach (Character_Setup character in Characters) {
            print (character.Weapon);
        }*/

        // Create 2 teams Off 3 Players

        // Team 1
        // Create Blue Team
        List<Character_Setup> Blue_Team = new List<Character_Setup> ();
        Blue_Team.AddRange (Characters);

        foreach (Character_Setup character in Blue_Team)
        {
            print (character.Weapon);
        }


        // Team 2
        //Create Red Team
        //List<Character_Setup> Red_Team = new List<Character_Setup> ();
        //Red_Team.AddRange (Characters);

    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

This code currently copies everything over. I want to be able to select something within Characters and copy it to Blue_Team.

I have been through the internet and I am a bit lost at the moment.

What can I do to copy just one section out of the characters list and then remove it?

Comment: What's your criteria on what section of your list should be copied? How many items should be copied? Can they be sequential, or do they need to be randomly selected? The copying/deleting part is simple enough, but you haven't given enough details about how you want to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking, this code will copy a single `Character` to `Blue_Team` based on the `Character.Weapon` value, but this  can be changed to whatever you like.

```
Character selectedChar = Characters.Where(objChar => objChar.Weapon == "Knife");

Blue_Team.Add(selectedChar);
```

If you want several objects, you can return a list instead with this code:

```
List<Character> selectedCharList = Characters.Where(objChar => objChar.Weapon == "Knife").ToList();

Blue_Team.AddRange(selectedCharList);
```

This approach uses `System.Linq`, which is incredibly handy when working with lists.  I use it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

First thanks for the answers. They did not give me the direct answer but they did lead me on the right path which led me to my answer. This is exactly what I needed.

I have also learnt to be clearer with my code and comments.

This is the code that I have written to achieve what i wanted.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Game_Play : MonoBehaviour {

    public int Num_Players = 11;
    public int Players = 1;




    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        //Section 1
        //Create a list
        // Using Character_Setup
        //add 10 characters to list

        List <Character_Setup> Characters = new List<Character_Setup> ();

        Characters.Add (new Character_Setup ("Flamethrower"));
        Characters.Add (new Character_Setup ("Shotgun"));
        Characters.Add (new Character_Setup ("Rifle"));
        Characters.Add (new Character_Setup ("Pistol"));
        Characters.Add (new Character_Setup ("Machine Gun"));
        Characters.Add (new Character_Setup ("Grenade Launcher"));
        Characters.Add (new Character_Setup ("Knife"));
        Characters.Add (new Character_Setup ("Rocket Launcher"));
        Characters.Add (new Character_Setup ("Throwing Star"));
        Characters.Add (new Character_Setup ("Sling Shot"));

        foreach (Character_Setup character in Characters) {
            print (character.Weapon);
        }

        //Section 2
        // Create 2 teams Off 3 Players

        // Team 1
        //Create Blue Team
        //use loop to fill team
        //Create Variable to hold selection number
        //Add to team
        //Remove from Characters availble
        List<Character_Setup> Blue_Team = new List<Character_Setup> ();
        while (Blue_Team.Count < 3)
        {
            Character_Setup PlayerSelection = Characters [UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, Characters.Count)];
            Blue_Team.Add (PlayerSelection);
            Characters.Remove(PlayerSelection);
        }

        foreach (Character_Setup character in Blue_Team)
        {
            print (character.Weapon);
        }

        // Team 2
        //Create Red Team
        List<Character_Setup> Red_Team = new List<Character_Setup> ();
        while (Red_Team.Count < 3)
        {
            Character_Setup PlayerSelection = Characters [UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, Characters.Count)];
            Red_Team.Add (PlayerSelection);
            Characters.Remove(PlayerSelection);
        }

        foreach (Character_Setup character in Red_Team)
        {
            print (character.Weapon);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have a `Team` property in your `Character_Setup` class, then you can select who goes into what list by that property. Should have an enum backing it.. but to get started just add `public int Team = 0`, then in the constructor allow assigning `Team = 1` for "blue team" and `Team = 2` for "red team" (team 0 is "no team", up to you if you want to support that or not, if not just allow 1 and 2, not 0, 1, 2).

Then you can do, `Blue_Team.AddRange(Characters.Where(c => c.Team == 1));`.

Another way to do it without LINQ is like this:

```
foreach (var charact in Characters)
{
    if (charact.Team == 1)
    {
        Blue_Team.Add(charact);
    }

    if (charact.Team == 2)
    {
        Red_Team.Add(charact);
    }    
}
```